# Protractor: Webdriver-manager update downloads an incompatible version of chromedriver

Tags: protractor, webdriver-manager

Chrome Browser version in my machine 116.0.5845.111 (Official Build) (64-bit).
But Webdriver manager downloads chromedriver_114.0.5735.90.

Error:

> E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
> Current browser version is 116.0.5845.111 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

I have tried below commands but not able to download correct one.

1. "webdriver-manager update",
2. "webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 116.0.5845.111"